# check if Field is exists firebase rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[image]

I want to check if the Field exists in a document in the firestore.
but I get this error

```
Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [8], column [24]. Null value error.
```

Comment: While the documentation says that `in` works on a map, I typically check explicitly against the `keys` of the map. So: `'providerId' in resource.data.keys`.

Comment: thanks, sir it fixed my issue